# Azure DevOps check if password exist in KeyVault inside of the following bash script (yml pipeline)

Tags: bash, azure, azure-devops, azure-keyvault

E.g. passwordKey = `dbPassword` it may be or may be not in Azure KeyVault.

The problem is how can I reference a secret variable by using its name which is another variable?

`$(!passwordKey)` does not work :(

Cause inside the bash task var `password` becomes equal string "$(!passwordKey)" not the value of the `dbPassword` var.

```
- task: AzureKeyVault@1
   inputs:
     azureSubscription: 'dev'
     KeyVaultName: '$(KeyVaultName)'
     SecretsFilter: '*'

- task: Bash@3
  displayName: 'Bash checks if $(passwordKey) exists'
  env:
    password: $(!passwordKey)
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: env
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: What is the error that you are getting?

Comment: I have edited the question with "Cause inside the bash task var password becomes equal string "$(!passwordKey)" not the value of the dbPassword var."

Comment: Why do you have a `!` before `passwordKey`?

Comment: @mibrl12 Not get your response for several days, would you please share your latest information about this issue? If the below answer solve your problem, would you please accept it as the answer? So it would be helpful for other members who get the same issue to find the solution easily. If you have any concern, feel free to share it here. Have a nice day.

Answer (score -1):

While using the AzureKeyVault task, values are retrieved as strings. For example, if there is a secret named connectionString, a task variable connectionString is created with the latest value of the respective secret fetched from Azure key vault. This variable is then available in subsequent tasks like $(connectionString)

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/azure-key-vault?view=azure-devops#arguments

I am able to access the password:

```
steps:
- bash: |
   # Write your commands here

   echo "Hello World"
   echo " vault value - $(amgartest)"

  displayName: 'Bash Script'
```

EDIT: Adding environment variable:

```
steps:
- bash: |
   echo "Db password is -$(passwordNameKey)-"

   echo "Environment variable password = $password"

  displayName: 'Bash Script'
  env:
    password: $(passwordNameKey)
```

If the key-value pair of `passwordNameKey=dbPassword` exists in KeyVault, the environment variable `password` will be set with the value of `passwordNameKey` which is `dbPassword`, otherwise the environment variable `password` will be `$(passwordNameKey)`.

Comment: "A list of additional items to map into the process's environment. For example, secret variables are not automatically mapped"
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/bash?view=azure-devops#arguments

Comment: Is it in your case: amgartest=passwordNameKey ?

Comment: Yes, in my case `amgartest=passwordNameKey` I will edit my script to suit your variable names